# Receiving runtime error with type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Series<dynamic, num>>' charts_flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get the `charts_flutter` for flutter, and I've used the `LineChart` example with modifications to fit into my app. I'm not receiving any build errors, however, I'm receiving a run time error of

```
'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Series<dynamic, num>>'
```

here is the code for building the chart

```
  _buildChart() {


    if (seriesList == null) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return new charts.LineChart(seriesList, animate: true);
    }
  }
```

and I'm filling the series as:

```
setState(() {
                  seriesList = [
                    charts.Series<Stat, num>(
                      id: 'Income',
                      colorFn: (_, __) =>
                          charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
                      domainFn: (Stat stat, _)=> stat.month,
                      measureFn: (Stat stat, _) => stat.amount,
                      data: stats.monthlyIncomes.data,
                    )
                  ];
```

From what I can see I'm doing exactly what the example is showing, but I'm receiving this error - what would i need to resolve this ?

Comment: add declaration of `seriesList`

Comment: hi its List<charts.Series> seriesList; I tried to follow it as close to the example at https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `seriesList` declaration to

```
List<charts.Series<Stat, num>> seriesList= []
```

Comment: Hi I just tried that tried that and there was an error : The type 'List' is declared with 1 type parameters, but 2 type arguments were given.
Try adjusting the number of type arguments to match the number of type parameters.

Comment: Ok, based on your response I changed it to List<charts.Series<Stat, num>> seriesList; and that seems to have done it. Thanks heaps for your help, would you be able to update your answer to this can I can accept it ?

Comment: What if my Series List <State, DateTime> (so DateTime is the domain type). I still get this type error with `num`, I don't know where the runtime pull out this num

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086092/how-can-i-avoid-charts-flutter-datetime-based-series-lists-runtime-type-excepti