# How can I avoid charts_flutter DateTime based Series List's runtime type exception?

Tags: flutter, charts

My model:

```
class Record {
  final DateTime timeStamp;
  final int metric;
}
```

I'd like to display a series of that on the simplest possible `LineChart`.

```
List<Record> _sampledRecords;
...
@override
initState() {
  _sampledRecords = ...
}
...
              child: LineChart(
                [
                  Series<Record, DateTime>(
                    id: 'Metric 1',
                    colorFn: (_, __) =>
                        MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
                    domainFn: (Record record, _) => record.timeStamp,
                    measureFn: (Record record, _) => record.metric,
                    data: _sampledRecords,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Now this is completely in concert with several example code I saw, like check out https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/nonzero_bound_measure_axis
Clearly the headcount is the measurement there (y axis data) and the `DateTime` is the x axis data. I typed my use-case exactly the same way and the compiler is OK with it.

However runtime I get: `type 'List<Series<Record, DateTime>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Series<dynamic, num>>'`. Where does the system pulls this `num` numeric typing from? I cannot use [Receiving runtime error with type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Series<dynamic, num>>' charts_flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967117/receiving-runtime-error-with-type-listseriesdynamic-dynamic-is-not-a-subt) (so please realize my question is NOT a duplicate) solution, because `DateTime` is not a `num` type. I tried this as a clarification, but it didn't change anything:

```
              child: LineChart(
                <Series<Record, DateTime>>[
                  Series<Record, DateTime>(
                    id: 'Metric 1',
                    colorFn: (_, __) =>
                        MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
                    domainFn: (Record record, _) => record.timeStamp,
                    measureFn: (Record record, _) => record.metric,
                    data: _sampledRecords,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

---

I refactored the code like this:

```
List<Series<Record, DateTime>> _getPowerData() {
  return [
    Series<Record, DateTime>(
      id: 'Metric 1',
      colorFn: (_, __) =>
      MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
      domainFn: (Record record, _) => record.timeStamp,
      measureFn: (Record record, _) => record.power,
      data: _sampledRecords,
    ),
  ];
}

              child: LineChart(_getPowerData()
```

I get `type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Series<dynamic, num>>'` runtime exception. Furthermore, I even tried to satisfy the `num` type with `int`:

```
List<Series<Record, int>> _getPowerData() {
  return [
    Series<Record, int>(
      id: 'Metric 1',
      colorFn: (_, __) =>
      MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
      domainFn: (Record record, _) => record.seconds,
      measureFn: (Record record, _) => record.power,
      data: _sampledRecords,
    ),
  ];
}
```

But even this yields the `type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Series<dynamic, num>>'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the simple `LineChart` is not geared to handle time series data. Let's take the `NonzeroBoundMeasureAxis` (https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/nonzero_bound_measure_axis) for example: it uses `TimeSeriesChart`. So I was in a wrestling match with `LineChart` whereas I should have just picked a more specialized chart (there are multiple) which support time series based data.